# How to get the ScrollViewer to scroll after statically set index containing List inside?

Tags: c#, silverlight, scrollbar, silverlight-5.0, scrollviewer

I am using Silverlight 5 and C# to create a scroll bar.

I am have ListBox and I create a scrollbar and inside that scrollbar I display a List of items like this: (My code shows all the 7 items but I just want to display 3 items without scrolling rest 4 by scrolling)

```
        TextBlock txtblkShowStatus = null;
        ListBox lines = new ListBox();
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        lines.ItemsSource = param.Component.Attributes.Items;
        scrollViewer.Content = lines;
        scrollViewer.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        scrollViewer.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(3); //By this line i want to display the only 3 items (out of7).
       //I mean the other 4 items must be visible on scrolling.

        Grid.SetColumn(scrollViewer, 1);          
        childGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);

        txtblkShowStatus = generateTextBlock();
        lines.SelectionChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            txtblkShowStatus.Text = lines.SelectedItem.ToString();
        };
        lines.SelectedIndex = 2; //It will display énd item in txtblkShowStatus when no clikc happens at starting.
        Grid.SetColumn(txtblkShowStatus, 2);
        childGrid.Children.Add(txtblkShowStatus); //This childGrid contain a row with 3 columns.
```

By this line scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(3); i want to display only 3 items out of 7 .I mean the other 4 items must be visible on scrolling the scrollbar.

**NOTE: Please note that i don't have to use `height` , i need to deal with index because i will set the index statically and it must show just the values until that index and rest value will be displayed on scrolling.** (if you have anyother idea to achieve it please explain it).

How to do the achieve this?

Comment: can you post your GenerateTextblock code!

Comment: @Sajeetharan just done

Comment: Oh sorry . It just creates a textblock and center it and returns it in txtblkShowStatus .

Comment: Oh sorry . It just creates a textblock and center it and returns it in txtblkShowStatus

Comment: You want to display only 4 items of listbox initially?

Comment: Yes. It depends upon the static value (here it is 3 in my question). Then it must show 3 items without scrolling and rest 4 by scrolling (suppose i have 7 total items). The answer written below by "rae1" do this but he deals with height but i want to deal with index or something more better then height (if you know).

Comment: @Sajeetharan have you found any solution for it ? Do you think that any solution to this problem exists ?

Comment: what you can do is, assign the listboxitems height inside foreach and set the index you want to display, mulitply the index with listbox heigh and set it as the size of the scrollviewer

Comment: Could you please answer it below with a little piece of explained code so that i would be able ot mark as answer ?Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to rae1's suggestion,

```
        int index = 5; //say you want to display upto 5th element
        ListBox lines = new ListBox();
        lines.Width = 100;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            lines.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem
                        {
                           Content = i.ToString()
                        });
        }
        foreach (ListBoxItem lv in lines.Items)
        {
            lv.Height = 10;

        }
        scrollViewer.Height = index * 10;
        scrollViewer.Content = lines;
        Grid.SetColumn(scrollViewer, 1);
        childGrid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);
```

Comment: @Sajeentharan I didn't implemented. I am doing some other task in same project after that i will implement it as the current finishes but i saw your approach. But i guess it will not be implemented for combo box (if i want to achieve the same approach for combo box item display).

Answer (score 1):

The `ScrollToVerticalOffset` method [does not do what you are trying to use it for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It will scroll only when there is a need to. In your case you are seeing all 7 elements because the *space* allows you to see them.

If you want to only show the first three items you need to modify the `Height` property for the `ScrollViewer` and set it to a proper value.

If you have 7 items, and each items is `10px` in height, and the height of the ScrollViewer is `100px` there is not need to scroll because all items can be fitted in the space given. However, if you change the height to `30px`, then the `ScrollViewer` only has `30px` to display a `70px` content size, and thus you need to scroll to see the rest of the items, achieving the effect you are after.

Comment: Is it posssible to deal with the index of list instead of height ? Anf how to achieve this with height ?

Comment: You just need to set the `Height` to a smaller value. Changing the index won't affect what you are trying to do.

Comment: You mean there is NO way to display only the items(i mean 3 in my case ) statically to any particular index of the number of items ?Ans rest by scrolling .

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the idea behind a `ScrollViewer`. If you have 7 items, and each items is `10px` in height, and the height of the ScrollViewer is `100px`, how exactly do you envision only showing the first 3 items? In this scenario there is not need to scroll because all items can be fitted in the space given. If you change the height to `30px` however, then the Scrollviewer only has `30px` to display a `70px` content size, and thus you need to scroll to see the rest of the items.

Comment: Is height only the possible way to display the desired number of items ? But i am asked to do it for index of that list.I have to set any value statically and the scrollviewer must show only those number of items without scrolling and others must be viewed by scrolling. Is it possible to achieve what i want to do ?

Comment: If it needs to be dependent on the index of the list, simply make the height proportional to it. However, I think there is something wrong in the requirements or your understanding because you are trying to negate the exact purpose of a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Is it fix that each  items is 10px in height .If not then is there any way to know height of each item. So that i wwould be implement what you said.

Comment: That would depend on what you are showing; I do not know the details of your design. However, it is strange that you are required to this, as it will be a hack it the best of cases.